# How to retrieve records based on Yesterday date in c#?

Tags: c#

Date_Of_Event.Date <= DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(-1))

Comment: Please provide more information: Where and how you want to query data (Linq, ADO.net etc)

Comment: I see that you are new to SO, but as you already have asked several questions, I thought I would remind you to upvote the questions that are helpful to you, and check of the most helpful question as the accepted answer. That will give the guys in here furter incentive to help you. If you don't know how, read the faq or ask :)

Answer (score 5):

You have the comparison backwards

```
// This should work in LINQ-to-SQL / EntityFramework
Date_Of_Event >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
&&
Date_Of_Event < DateTime.Today
```

or

```
// This will work in LINQ-to-Objects or anywhere else, really.
Date_Of_Event.Date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
```

As a side note, it may be a good idea to store the value of `DateTime.Today` in a variable, so that weird bugs don't show up around midnight (or 11:00pm or 1:00am depending on daylight saving time).

Answer (score 3):

```
Date_Of_Event.Date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
```

This will remove the time part of the date time, and keep only the date so you can check for equality instead of the time being inside the correct interval.

Comment: You shouldn't have the .Day bit in - you're currently comparing an integer with a DateTime.

Comment: @Jon - Correct as always. Thanks. Updated my answer now.